# Derivatives of equivalent equations aren't equivalent.

Tags: calculus

When I take the derivative of the formula $y=\frac{1}{x}$ with respect to $x$, I get the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.

However, when I take the derivative of the equation $xy=1$, which is equivalent to the first one, I get $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$.

How come these two derivatives are not equivalent, since the original equations are equivalent?

Comment: Plug $y = \frac1{x}$ into the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be equivalent. Consider

$$
0 = \frac{d1}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} (xy) = y \frac{dx}{dx} + x \frac{dy}{dx} = y + x \frac{dy}{dx}.
$$

So you have

$$
y + x \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{y}{x}
$$

but $y = \frac{1}{x}$ so substituing you get

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{x^2}
$$